# How to get partitioned cookies in chrome extension

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension

I've developped a chrome extension for my personal use that copies cookies from a domain to another.

In my manifest (v3) i have host permission set to :

```
"host_permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*"
  ],
```

I noticed that when i use the `chrome.cookies.getAll({domain :'exemple')` function it does not returns the cookies that have a partition key.

Is there a way to get theese cookies ?

Comment: It's a bug, fixed in https://crbug.com/323924496 yesterday, so it'll be available in Chrome Canary today or in a couple of days, and in the stable channel in about a month. Judging by the description of the bug you can try getAll() to get all cookies and filter the array by domain yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answser, unfortunatly i tried getting all cookies and filtering it by domain after but the partitioned cookies are excluded from the return of `cookies.getAll`, i'll wait for the bug top be fixed :)